# Questions about proving by cases for a biconditional

Tags: proof-writing

Let's say I have a predicate, $\forall x\in h(x) : f(x) \leftrightarrow h(x) \lor g(x)$

I understand that when Q $\implies$ P that we do cases and assume both h(x) and g(x) in each case, however when it is P $\implies$ Q I'm not sure if I should break it into cases, as we cannot assume h(x) or g(x).

Comment: Can you explain your notation?

Answer (score 0):

Prove: $\forall x\in h(x) : f(x) \leftrightarrow h(x) \lor g(x)$

$\Leftarrow:$   Yes, proof by cases is used here.

- Case 1: By assuming $h(x)$ holds for any $x$, we must show $f(x)$ must hold too.
- Case 2: By assuming $g(x)$ holds for any $x$, we must show $f(x)$ must hold too.

$\Rightarrow:$   Here, by assuming $f(x)$ holds for some arbitrary $x$, we must show that *at least one* of either $g(x)$ or $h(x)$ holds (that it is impossible for *both* to *not* hold when the assumption does).   Proof by cases thus requires extra assumptions.

- Case 1: By assuming $f(x)$ holds *but* not $g(x)$, show that $h(x)$ must hold.
- Case 2: By assuming $f(x)$ holds *but* not $h(x)$, show that $g(x)$ must hold.

  Alternatively, you can demonstrate that whenever $h(x)$ and $g(x)$ both do not hold, then $f(x)$ cannot either.   (That is: proof by contradiction).

Comment: The 2nd case breakdown can be done a bit more cleanly like this: Assume $f(x)$ holds. If $g(x)$ holds, we are done. If not, then additionally assume that $g(x)$ does not hold and show that $h(x)$ must hold.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Yes, that works too.  A demonstration of $f(x)~\to~\Big(~g(x)~\vee~\big(\neg g(x)\wedge h(x)\big)~\Big)$ is enough.